# Is there a way to get the numbers on top of my colums in my histogram?

Tags: r

I can't get the numbers on top of my histogram.

```r
Histogram_penguins <- napenguins$bill_depth_mm

hist (Histogram_penguins, 
     main = "Snavelhoogte van alle Palmer Penguins",
     xlab = "Snavelhoogte in mm",
     xlim = c (12,24),
     ylab = "frequentie",
     col = "purple",
     freq = TRUE,
     text (Histogram_penguins[["mids"]], Histogram_penguins[["counts"]], labels= Histogram_penguins[["counts"]], adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
)
```

Getting error:

```r
Error in Histogram_penguins[["mids"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

But if I use the `$` instead of `[[` it's also not working because of the atomic vector(s)?

```r
$mids
[1] 13.5 14.5 15.5 16.5 17.5 18.5 19.5 20.5 21.5

$xname
[1] "Histogram_penguins"
```

Comment: You should provide at least a subset of your data so we may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. `Histogram_penguins` is the full vector of original data, so it does not have the `[["mids"]]` that the `hist` function calculates and provides.
2. You cannot use the `text(.)` function within `hist`, it needs to be done outside of the call.

Try:

```r
H <- hist(mtcars$disp)
text(H[["mids"]], H[["counts"]], H[["counts"]], adj = c(0.5, -0.5))
```

[image]

You'll obviously want to look at the y-axis limits to preclude what happens here, where one column's number is outside of the original plot limits. One way could be

```r
H <- hist(mtcars$disp, plot = FALSE)
plot(H, ylim = c(0, max(H$counts) + 1), col = "gray")
text(H[["mids"]], H[["counts"]], H[["counts"]], adj = c(0.5, -0.5))
```

Note that you need to specify `plot(., col=)`, since the `hist(.)` defaults to a filling color, but `plot.hist` does not. Also, my premise of `max(H$counts)+1` works here, but with different datasets it might need to be something more.